# fscanf only reading first string but not next set of numbers

Tags: c

I'm currently working on a file that reads this information from a .txt file

```
Alpha 300 458 760
Gamma 197 222 435
Delta 666 777 888
Epsilon 123 456 77
Phi 515 120 98
```

From there I have to calculate the distance from 0,0,0 of these points. I then must put the Name and Distance into another file and print the name, x, y, z, and distance on the console.
My problem occurs when I try to fscanf to retrieve the date from the the .txt file but the only output I get is:

```
Name             X               Y               Z               Distance
Alpha    0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000
Gamma    0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000
Delta    0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000
Epsilon  0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000
Phi      0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000
```

It seems like it is only reading the first string but not the following numbers. Please help.

```
int main(void)
{
//Variables
double xCord,yCord,zCord, distanceOfObj = 0.0;
char locationName[NAMELEN];

//Open Location file and add pointer
FILE *locationFile = fopen ("location.txt","r");

//Open distance file and add pointer
FILE *distanceFile = fopen ("distance.txt","w");

//Header for screen and distance file
fprintf(distanceFile, "Name \t\t Distance \t\n");
printf ("Name \t\t X \t\t Y \t\t Z \t\t Distance \n");

//Extract information
while (!feof(locationFile))
{
    fscanf(locationFile, "%s %lf %lf %lf", &locationName, &xCord, &yCord, &zCord);
    distanceOfObj = calcDistance(xCord, yCord, zCord);
    fprintf(distanceFile, "%s\t\t %lf\n", &locationName, &distanceOfObj);
    printf ("%s\t %lf\t %lf\t %lf\t %lf\n", &locationName, &xCord, &yCord, &zCord, &distanceOfObj);
}

//Close files
fclose(locationFile);
fclose(distanceFile);`

}
```

Comment: Unlike with `scanf`, when you call `printf`, you should pass the *values* of your variables, not their addresses.  For strings, too, though it is a bit of a C quirk that strings tend to work either way.

Comment: What errors/warnings did your compiler report, and why did you ignore them?

Comment: Also, see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: `NAMELEN` is too small.

Comment: Grace Rombach, Save time.  Enable all warnings.